# C#,Visual Studio 2010 , Git and AppHarbor

Tags: visual-studio, git, appharbor

I installed git on visual studio 2010 (the installation is done well) 
the problem is that I can not download my project in AppHarbor
using git GUI.But If I use (clone git @ https://username appharbor.com / projet.git) 
I get the project.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) includes a plugin for VS2010.

Comment: I installed git on visual studio 2010 (the installation is done well) 
the problem is that I can not download my project in AppHarbor
using git GUI.But If I use (clone git @ https://username appharbor.com / projet.git) 
I get the project.
thank you

Comment: @saisne Instead of copying and pasting your question why don't you specify what you mean by "I installed git on visual studio 2010".  If the installation really is done well then surely it's giving you an error message of sorts.  Post more information other than I installed XXX and its not working.

Answer (score 3):

GitExtensions and AppHarbor do not play well together in my experience.

AppHarbor does not use SSH instead you are prompted for your password. GitExtensions does not recognise this prompt and does not let you enter your password. It just appears to hang.

The Git GUI in msysgit does however prompt you for your password, so it is possible and something that needs fixing in GitExtensions.

I just push/pull from AppHarbor with the CLI personally.

Comment: I will recommend you to use GitHub or Bitbucket for your repositories and then add an AppHarbor hook/service. In this way you will be able to use SSH. [GitHub integration](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/integrating-with-github) [Bitbucket integration](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/api/integrating-with-bitbucket)

Answer (score 0):

In my workflow, I use [***GitHub for Windows***](http://windows.github.com/) for almost all Git operations, it's very intuitive and you can jump to *Explorer* or a shell at any time. And for automatic deployment and testing, I've configure **GitHub**'s Hooks to deploy to [***AppHarbor***](https://appharbor.com/) from the link on my application's Settings page:

`https://appharbor.com/applications/[your_app]/edit`